# How i can Set an existing LiveConnectSession to the LiveConnectClient?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, onedrive

i'm trying to implement a multi connexion on my ios app so i can add two oneDrive account on my app , so i need to save the  LiveConnectSession and set it to the current LiveConnectClient but the session property of the LiveConnectClient is readonly , so is there any way to do this?

I was thinking to save the accessToken ,authenticationToken,refreshToken,scopes,expires of the LiveConnectSession and then do:

```
initWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken
authenticationToken:(NSString *)authenticationToken
       refreshToken:(NSString *)refreshToken
             scopes:(NSArray *)scopes
            expires:(NSDate *)expires;
```

thanks

Comment: it is possible, I have came across the app "AirFile", have a look.

Comment: please can you provide a link ?

Comment: search app store with "AirFile" download free version, it will allowed you to add only 2 accounts add both "OneDrive"

Comment: i need the source code i don't need to see it please if you can help me to do this i will be thankful

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing..convey me if you have..I will also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to accomplish this.

Comment: Could you explain the technical limitations that make this impossible?